# Save last entity in collection last

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a collection of entities in a collection, each entity has a time field that specifies when they were created.

What I want to do is save every entity in the list except the last one, and then the last one in a second SaveChanges(). I want this because if I have a set of new entities I want the last one saved last to trigger code in a stored procedure for insert.

eg:

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = Account.dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
 {

Tranasction t = Account.Transactions.OrderBy(t => t.CreationDate).Last();
Account.Transactions.Remove(t);

Account.dbContext.SaveChanges();

Account.Transactions.Add(t);

Account.dbContext.SaveChanges();


dbContextTransaction.Commit();
}
```

My question is - is this possible?  Currently the only way that I thought would work would be to mark the entity as unmodified or detatched but both dont work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something is really fishy about your design if you need to do this. What are you trying to accomplish with that code in the stored procedure?

Comment: I know its a bit of a specific thing to ask, my reason is because say I have an application that lets you put 5 withdrawals on an account. Each one making the balance smaller and smaller until the balance reaches zero. This would effectively close the account. The back end closes the account when a transaction is passed that zeros the account (which triggers some specific code). Because of restrictions on the minimum value an account can be I need to be able to order the save of my transactions on the account.

Comment: Currently the only way I can see of doing this is to not add the final transaction I want to save last and instead store it in a temporary collection. When it comes to save time then save the model as it is, then add the remaining transaction to the account and save again.